# Getting my transcripts as numbers instead of selected text language, using google speech to text api

Tags: python, google-speech-to-text-api

I am doing a real time speech to text conversion for a specified language, but whenever I run the code, I am getting the transcipt as numbers instead of the specified language.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKJj2.png)

I am able to view the transcript correctly in google cloud, but in my local machine, the transcript occurs as numbers, not the language I want.

Comment: Those are all escape sequences; you have to decode the bytes as utf-8 to see the actual characters.

Comment: Please refrain from posting code in images. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. I was unable to iterate the json file actually.
Its simple, we just have to use (response_standard_mp3.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript), and we get the transcript as requested.